# How can I specify the language of the output text for Hugging Face Transformers?

Tags: python

Using a pipeline:
I would like to be able to specify the language for the output text. How can I do this? Here is my code that works. It outputs English regardless of the input audio language.

```
filename = "/Users/warrenz/Temp/mp3 files/lfb_IN_003.mp3"

model = "openai/whisper-large-v2"

from transformers import pipeline

pipe = pipeline("automatic-speech-recognition", model=model)

result = pipe(filename)
print(result['text'])

# This will output English, no matter what the input language is.
```